# A question about hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, sample-size

Question

[image]

I am actually finding no clue how to start with this sum. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please use specific titles for your questions; most of your questions begin along the lines of  "A question about..."

Comment: I shall keep that in mind from the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a $N(\mu,\sigma_0^2)$ population for the amount of reduction of blood pressure with $\sigma_0^2$ known, one can show that the UMP test of size $\alpha=0.05$ (say) for testing $H:\mu=10$ versus $K:\mu>10$ is given by

$$\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar x-10)}{\sigma_0}>z_{0.05}\approx 1.645 \\ 0 &,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases} $$

You are given that power of the test $\varphi$ at $\mu=15$ is $0.95$.

Using this information, you can find an explicit relation between the sample size $n$ and $\sigma_0$.

I don't see how to find the *minimum* sample size for which the power is $0.95$, or how to find a relation between the *minimum* sample size and $\sigma_0$.